# referencing a type from within an xsd pattern

Tags: regex, xsd

I want to recognize all of my servers over my office network. They have a particular naming pattern which only I use. I've defined it in a `simpleType`. 
Now I was told I have to filter my servers from a list of full `DNS` names (like `www.bla.moo.oneofmyservers.foo.loo`). My naming strategy has a length limit. I would have simply put it inside a `*mystrategy*` if not for that.

**Is there a way to reference my type from within a pattern definition?**

It didn't work when I wrote `*mytype*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you're asking is something like this:

*I have a pattern and I've used it as a constraining facet in a simple type; now, I want to make another type, and for maintenance purposes, I wish to somehow reference that pattern, so that I don't have to maintain it in two different places...*

The answer is no, you can't. Constraining facets in XSD are not referenceable entities; nor types are referenceable within constraining facets.